# Problem upgrading Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my version on Ubuntu from 9.10 to 10.04 (and eventually to the latest), but I'm having trouble with broken packages.

I've tried:

- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade
- dpkg --configure -a (not sure why)

I'm not sure what's relevant, so I'm going to dump what I've got:

### Output from upgrade attempt:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Done Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tool
Done downloading            
extracting 'lucid.tar.gz'
authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg' 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
Done downloading            
Reading package lists: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done

Updating repository information
WARNING: Failed to read mirror file
Done downloading            

Checking package manager
Reading package lists: Donelucid-security/multiverse Packages: 96   gutsy/restricted Packages: 02  
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade: 
E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug against the 
'update-manager' package and include the files in 
/var/log/dist-upgrade/ in the bug report. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists: Donekarmic-security/multiverse Packages: 95   utsy/restricted Packages: 02  
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
Reading state information: Done
```

### /etc/apt/sources.list (with most of the comments stripped)

```
$ cat sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 9.10 _Karmic Koala_ - Release i386 (20091028.5)]/ karmic main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 7.10 _Gutsy Gibbon_ - Release i386 (20071016)]/ gutsy main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu karmic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu karmic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse

## Packages for Chrome
#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu karmic main
#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu karmic main

## Latest PHP packages
#deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
#deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security main
```

### The last few lines of /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log

```
2011-08-02 19:21:54,211 DEBUG entry 'deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2011-08-02 19:21:54,246 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2011-08-02 19:22:24,895 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-02 19:22:24,895 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked)
2011-08-02 19:22:29,991 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 30853
2011-08-02 19:22:29,991 DEBUG needServerMode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2011-08-02 19:26:29,025 DEBUG Installing 'upstart-logd' (priority in required set 'required' but not scheduled for install)
2011-08-02 19:26:30,695 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
2011-08-02 19:26:30,696 DEBUG abort called
2011-08-02 19:26:30,697 DEBUG openCache()
2011-08-02 19:26:30,698 DEBUG failed to SystemUnLock() (E:Not locked)
2011-08-02 19:26:33,728 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 29182
2011-08-02 19:26:33,728 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

(thanks)